# How to set Datadog trace id and span id in Android

Tags: android, logging, logback, slf4j, datadog

I am trying to get Datadog log tracing working in my Android application. Following is my setup.

Android app

- slf4j and logback for logging

Backend

- Spring boot application with slf4j for logging which correctly injects dd.trade_id and dd.span_id to the logs

Problem

- I can't get the trace_id and span_id to add to MDC attributes from Android

Here is a part of logback.xml from Android

```html
<appender name="Logcat" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
  <encoder>
    <Pattern>${logcat_log_pattern}</Pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="JSON_TCP" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
  <remoteHost>intake.logs.datadoghq.com</remoteHost>
  <port>${port}</port>
  <keepAliveDuration>20 seconds</keepAliveDuration>
  <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
    <prefix class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>${dd_api_key} %mdc{keyThatDoesNotExist}</pattern>
      </layout>
    </prefix>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFileMainApplication" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <file>${log_path}/log/mobile_kotlin.log</file>

  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
    <level>${level}</level>
  </filter>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <!-- daily rollover -->
    <fileNamePattern>${log_path}/log/mobile_kotlin.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

    <maxFileSize>${max_file_size}</maxFileSize>
    <maxHistory>${max_history}</maxHistory>
    <totalSizeCap>${total_size_cap}</totalSizeCap>
  </rollingPolicy>

  <encoder>
    <pattern>${file_log_pattern}</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

Here is a log from Spring Boot backend where dd.trace_id and dd.span_id is correctly set

```html
2022-08-17 04:46:54,954 INFO <package-name-removed> [http-nio-8081-exec-8] USER=<username_removed>, SEQ=1.0, REQ_ID=<req_id_removed>, dd.trace_id=<trace_id_removed>, dd.service=<service-name-removed>, dd.env=dev, dd.span_id=<span_id_removed>: Local user validation successful
```

PS:
The RUM SDK correctly populates trace id in the header in the Android request ("x-datadog-trace-id"). I tried adding AndroidTracer and getting trace_id according to [this](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-sdk-android/blob/master/docs/trace_collection.md) but it gives "0". Not the correct trace_id. Looks like activeSpan is not set. I also tried replacing the logger with Datadog default Android logger. It also fails to load trace_id because there is no activeSpan. I am new to both Datadog and OpenTracing. Help would be much appreciated.